# Provide Custom Value Binder in Handlebars.NET

Tags: c#, handlebars.js, handlebars.net

I'm trying to build a code generation framework using .net core and handlebars and I would need to customize how expressions are mapped to values in handlebars.net. Is it something that is possible? The closest I've been to is to transform my input object to a dictionary, but it does not give me the flexibility I need, is there any interfaces I can implement to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If I get your intent right you can have a look at [Handlebars.CSharp](https://github.com/zjklee/Handlebars.CSharp) > [IObjectDescriptorProvider](https://github.com/zjklee/Handlebars.CSharp/blob/master/source/Handlebars/ObjectDescriptors/IObjectDescriptorProvider.cs) ([usage example](https://github.com/zjklee/Handlebars.CSharp/issues/18#issuecomment-636470661)).

P.S. [Handlebars.CSharp](https://github.com/zjklee/Handlebars.CSharp) is a fork of [Handlebars.Net](https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net) maintained by me.

**Update:**

Mentioned functionality is already merged to [Handlebars.Net](https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a custom interface that transform any object to dictionary. Here's is the current implementations, if anyone ever need this eventually.

```
public interface IHandlebarsContextConverter
{
    IDictionary<string, object> Convert(object @object);
}

public class HandlebarsContextConverterFields : IHandlebarsContextConverter
{
    public IDictionary<string, object> Convert(object @object)
    {
        return @object.GetType()
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(@object));
    }
}

public class HandlebarsContextConverterProperties : IHandlebarsContextConverter
{
    public IDictionary<string, object> Convert(object @object)
    {
        return @object.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(@object, null));
    }
}

var converter = new HandlebarsContextConverterMerge(
        new HandlebarsContextConverterFields(),
        new HandlebarsContextConverterProperties());
```